# Palindrome checker program

Tags: java, beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, palindrome

I've been studying Java for some days and I'm just now starting to make some simple programs, I'd like to know if there's any 'noob' mistakes or habits that I could avoid.

In other words: ***how could my code be more streamlined to Java?***

My code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    private static String reverse_string(String my_string)
    {
        String reversed_string = "";
        for(int j = my_string.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            reversed_string = reversed_string + my_string.charAt(j);
        }
        return reversed_string;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Insert a 'String': ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String user_string = input.nextLine().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");

        if (user_string.equals(reverse_string(user_string)))
            {
                System.out.println("It is a palindrome.");
            } else
            {
                System.out.println("It is not a palindrome.");
            }
    }
}
```

I believe there are already other alternatives to my  `reverse_string` function, hence the 'reinventing the wheel' tag.

Comment: You know you don't actually have to produce a reversed copy of the string to check for palindromes, right?  Use indices for the start/end and walk inwards until you meet / cross in the middle.  (Handling Unicode surrogate pairs has to happen on the fly here, but I think it's possible to detect a surrogate pair when looking at the 2nd half.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Sounds like a good potential answer to me.

Comment: @MJ713: A rewrite from scratch isn't really a code *review*.  Examples of meet-in-the-middle implementations exist all over the place in all languages (although the vast majority are just for char[], not handling surrogate pairs).  e.g. the canonical SO Q&A's top answer: [Check string for palindrome](//stackoverflow.com/q/4138827) (which happens to be in Java).  Other answers there point out that Java's StringBuilder already has a `.reverse()` method so writing your own is unnecessary if you want simple (but inefficient) code

Comment: @PeterCordes Per [this meta answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5045/complete-code-rewrite): "Are answers that suggest complete rewrite of the code acceptable? Yes. Always. But not a code-only 'Here is how I would do it' answer."

Comment: @MJ713: Ah, I hadn't read that, and had the wrong impression from a comment that paraphrased it.  Thanks.  Anyway, given that there's a canonical Q&A about it on SO, and http://componentsprogramming.com/palindromes/ with detailed analysis of algorithm efficiency, I'm content to just link those and leave UTF-16 surrogate-pair handling as an exercise for the reader.  (Especially since I don't have a Java dev env set up to test anything I might write.)

Comment: Just a comment, but if your learning java you want to do something with objects not just static methods as you have here. As thats where the majority of the real world complexity will happen.

Comment: I'm still learning haha, but i'll see what i can do

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer your comment, yes there are equivalent of PEP8 in java. I suggest [`checkstyle`](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/), this plugin works in lots of IDE / text editors and can be configured with your code style.

### Code review

#### `reverse_string` method

1. In java, we try to use the upper-case version of [`Snake case`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) only on constants / enums. For the methods and variables, I suggest that you use the [`Camel case`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) style.

*Before*

```java
private static String reverse_string(String my_string) 
{
   //[..]
}
```

*After*

```java
private static String reverseString(String myString) 
{
   //[..]
}
```

2. When concatenating `String` in a loop, it's generally recommended to use a [`java.lang.StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to gain performance and take fewer operations.

```java
private static String reverseString(String myString) 
{
   StringBuilder reversedString = new StringBuilder();

   for (int j = myString.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
   {
      reversedString.append(myString.charAt(j));
   }

   return reversedString.toString();
}
```

If you want not to use it, then I suggest the `+=` operator instead of the `+`; it will give the same result and make the code shorter.

### Other observations

The code was missing a bit of formatting, but nothing too important, I sugest that you pick a formatter for your style (Horstmann style) depending on your IDE / text editor.

### Refactored code

```java
private static String reverseString(String myString)
{
   String reversedString = "";

   for (int j = myString.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
   {
      reversedString += myString.charAt(j);
   }

   return reversedString;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   System.out.print("Insert a 'String': ");

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   String userString = input.nextLine().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");

   if (userString.equals(reverseString(userString))) 
   {
      System.out.println("It is a palindrome.");
   } 
   else 
   {
      System.out.println("It is not a palindrome.");
   }
}
```

Comment: "Refactored code" section is still using snake case for the `reversed_string` variable. Also the last `}` is missing.

Comment: For clarity, you could explain that constants are written in ALL_CAPS snake case, not just _any_ snake case.

Comment: I'd suggest writing "Camel case" as "camelCase".  When underlined as a link, it looks like capitalized Snake_case.

Comment: Doesn't the official style guide for java recommend same-line braces, and not newline braces?

Comment: @Cruncher For C-like languages in general, it seems like [everyone has their favorite indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Brace_placement_in_compound_statements)...honestly it is more important to be consistent within a project, regardless of which style is actually picked. But yeah, I think same-line braces are "official" for Java.

Comment: @MJ713 I find it interesting how C-like languages, people just say to be consistent, but with languages like python people are like the gestapo when it comes to styling.

Comment: @Cruncher Whitespace actually has semantic meaning in Python, so there's both less room to play around and more reason to pay attention to style in the first place. There might also be historical factors; Python is younger than C, and its rise coincided with the rise of the web, which may have made it easier to share/enforce style standards...I'm just speculating.

Answer (score 10):

In java is the preferred way of curly brace placing on the same line like you can see in code snippets in [Oracles Style Guide](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141270.html).

---

`reverse_string` has a [type embedded](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/) in its name which leads to a code smell.

The disadvantage is that if you want to change the type of the parameter you have to change the method name too.

Additional the invocation looks messy and redundant compared to a method name without the embedded type:

> ```java
> if (user_string.equals(reverse_string(user_string)))
> ```

compared to

```java
if (user_string.equals(reverse(user_string)))
```

---

Code can be descriptive by choosing good variable names.

> ```java
> Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
> String user_string = input.nextLine().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
> ```

I think `input` fits better than `user_string` to describe the input of a user:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");

if (input.equals(reverse(input))) { /*...*/ }
```

---

> ```java
> if (user_string.equals(reverse_string(user_string)))
> {
>   System.out.println("It is a palindrome.");
> } else
> {
>   System.out.println("It is not a palindrome.");
> }
> ```

The two `System.out.println` are a bit like a duplication. You could save the message you want to print in a variable and then print it once to the console:

```java
String message;
if (user_string.equals(reverse_string(user_string))) {
  message = "It is a palindrome.";
} else {
  message = "It is not a palindrome.";
}

System.out.println(message);
```

Or even shorter with the [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/IRWUG/ch21s03s01s02.html):

```java
String message = user_string.equals(reverse_string(user_string)) ? "It is a palindrome." : "It is not a palindrome.";
System.out.println(message);
```

---

I know that this a small script but I would like to introduce to think in objects:

```
public class Main {

  private static final WhiteSpaceFreeScanner scanner = new WhiteSpaceFreeScanner(new Scanner(System.in));

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Input input = scanner.nextLine();

    String message = input.isPalindrome() ? "It is a palindrome." : "It is not a palindrome.";
    System.out.println(message);
  }
}
```

```java
class WhiteSpaceFreeScanner {

  private final Scanner scanner;

  CustomScanner(Scanner scanner) {
    this.scanner = scanner;
  }

  Input nextLine() {
    String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
    return new Input(input);
  }

}
```

```java
class Input {
  private final String value;

  public Input(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  Input reversed() { /* ... */ }

  boolean isPalindrome() {
    return this.equals(reversed());
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) { /* ... */ }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: While the object example seems clearly over-engineered to me, it is a good learning point. +1 just for composition over inheritance. EDIT: Any reason to not publicize reversed? While not required for the program specifically, it would be generally useful for the api. EDIT2: Nvm, forgot java default is same-package, not protected

Comment: `String message = "It is" + (user_string.equals(reverse_string(user_string)) ? "":"not" ) +" a palindrome.";`  - very nice review!!!

Comment: `CustomScanner` would be an `AlphaNumericScanner` or an `WhiteSpaceFreeScanner` if it would remove other white space

Answer (score 9):

[Doi9t's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/237527/192133) is very good, but even with their improvements, there is still a problem: your code does not produce the correct answer in all cases.

Java strings use [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoding. This means that a Java `char` is not large enough to store all Unicode characters. Instead some characters (for example, ) are stored as a *pair* of `char`s, and reversing the pair (as your code does) will result in nonsense data. See [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) for more details.

Fortunately, the way UTF-16 is defined, `char`s that are *surrogates* (half-characters) have a completely separate range of values from `char`s that are Unicode characters by themselves. This means it is possible to test each `char` individually to see if it is a surrogate, and then have special handling to preserve the pairs.

```
import java.lang.Character;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.Scanner;

<...>

    private static String reverseString(String myString) {
       StringBuilder reversedString = new StringBuilder();

       for (int j = myString.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
          char c = myString.charAt(j);
          if (Character.isLowSurrogate(c)) {
              j--;
              reversedString.append(myString.charAt(j));
          }
          reversedString.append(c);
       }

       return reversedString.toString();
    }
```

If you *really* wanted to re-invent the wheel, I think `Character.isLowSurrogate(c)` could be replaced with `c >= '\uDC00' && c <= '\uDFFF'`, though I have not personally tested this.

---

As [Peter Cordes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/50567/peter-cordes) pointed out in a comment, we do not even *need* to reverse the string in order to detect a palindrome. Instead we can examine the input string in place, comparing the first character to the last, the second to the next-to-last, etc., until we reach the middle. This may be more performant.

We need special handling for 2-`char` characters in this case as well; fortunately, the String class has methods for pulling *code point* values instead of pulling `char` values directly.

- `codePointAt(int index)` behaves similarly to `charAt(int index)` in most cases, but if the `char` at the given index is the first half of a surrogate pair, it will return the full value of the pair.
- `codePointBefore(int index)` approaches the problem from the other end; if the `char` *before* the given index is the *last* half of a surrogate pair, it will return the full value of the pair.

```
    private static boolean isPalindrome(String myString) {
        int len = myString.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; ++i) {
            int frontHalfCharacter = myString.codePointAt(i);
            int backHalfCharacter = myString.codePointBefore(len - i)
            if (frontHalfCharacter != backHalfCharacter) {
                return false;
            }
            if (Character.isSupplementaryCodePoint​(frontHalfCharacter)) {  // i.e. if this is a 2-char character
                i++;
            }
        }
        return true;    
    }
```

---

And while we're on the topic of Unicode, you should of course read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), if you haven't already.

Comment: Knowing that a letter can take two characters is vital. A close next is the StringBuilder.reverse() method. :)

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen They deliberately chose to do it the hard way, hence the [reinventing-the-wheel tag](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel).

Comment: OP specifically asked for an alternative to the home grown reverse algorithm. The reinventing-the-wheel tag is stupid because it uses categorization tools as content and the tag name doesn't describe it's purpose. You have to go read the tag's description to figure out what it means.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen OP didn't actually ask for alternatives, they just said they were aware that alternatives probably existed...but I see your point. Maybe post to https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 2):

For `reverse_string`, it would probably be most efficient to create an array of `char`s and then construct a string from it. Note that I have not tested this code.

```java
private static String reverse_string(String my_string)
{
    char[] chars = new char[my_string.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++I)
    {
        chars[i] = my_string.charAt(chars.length - 1 - i); // The two indices can be swapped
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually need to create the reversed string. Why not just go over the string from both directions.

```
  String palindrome = "radar";
  isPalindrome(palindrome, 0, palindrome.length() -1);     

  // Could be converted to loop if wanted.
  private static boolean isPalindrome(String candidate, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    if(startIndex >= endIndex) {
      // Has passed each other or pointing towards same character.
      return true;
    }
    else if (candidate.charAt(startIndex) == candidate.charAt(endIndex)) {
      return isPalindrome(candidate, startIndex + 1, endIndex - 1);
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, great idea! I'll try that later